# When $parent.foo is a prototype method, the this is not the parent, workaround?

Tags: knockout.js

In my view model I have prototype methods where the *this* context is the item in the for each, not the actual view model. How do I achieve this?

```
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.methodThatNeedsAccesToTheParentViewModel">Edit</button>
```

ViewModel:

```
ViewModel.prototype.methodThatNeedsAccesToTheParentViewModel= function () {
        this = duff //this is the item in the foreach, not the real parent
    };
```

Ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to actually get the *this* variable in your method to point to your *ViewModel* instance? Or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not pass the function directly to the click binding, wrap it in an anonymous function to have it called in context of your view model:

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { $parent.methodThatNeedsAccesToTheParentViewModel() }">Edit</button>
```

this way when the binding is activated it will use $parent as context of the call - i.e. *this*

It is worth noting (since we can't see the structure of the file bindings) that the *$parent* variable will refer to the **binding** preceding the current item being iterated, which is not necessarily the parent of the item in the object graph.

**Edit**: i was missing some parenthesis above...

**Edit 2**: this works due to the way the binding is resolved. When the binding is applied by knockout the expression is resolved and must evaluate to a *function* (and hence why when you bind directly to a function there is no need for the parenthesis). This function is then called when the click binding is activated.

But here's the catch, since the **this** keyword in prototypal javascript is not bound by the owner of the function (i.e. where it is defined), but rather upon the way it is called (as explained better in [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) in this case knockout call the function not through the object that owns it (which would correctly bind the **this** operator), but binding it explicitly to its current binding context (since it cannot possibly know which instance the function was taken originally). You can replicate this behaviour by getting a reference to your function and then binding it to another object at call time - an example:

```
A = function() {
   this.name = "foo";
};
A.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name; };

a = new A();

console.log(a.getName()); // should log "foo" as expected

f = a.getName; // now f contains a reference to the function

console.log(f()); // this call the function in the current scope - most likely the window, and return nothing

b = new Object(); // another generic object - suppose this is knockout binding context

console.log(f.call(b)); // this bind the call explicitly to b, but since b has no name property,  nothing is returned again

console.log(f.call(a)); // this time we bind the function call to an object that has a name proerty, so the correct value is returned
```

On the other hand, by creating an anonymous function you are calling your method *explicitly* in the scope of the wanted object ($parent), so **this** is bound correctly.

I hope that helps a bit... :)

Comment: AFAIK $parent is the current item in the foreach binding so I hope it works. Sometimes I wonder what the point of using protype when running into these issues. Can you point to the source that explains how the function() { ... gives the correct context?

Comment: Yep, as soon as I got on my bike to go home, I thought of doing it this way!

Comment: I've not seen much explicit documentation on this form applied to objects, but it can mostly be desumed from the [click binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) where the anonymous function is used with a function.

Comment: @FutuToad I added some comments to my answer regarding why it works that way

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and I resolved it in this way:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.methodThatNeedsAccesToTheParentViewModel.bind($parent)">Edit</button>
```

Comment: I also prefer this syntax, I don't like seeing `function() {...}` stuff in my views.

Answer (score 0):

You've got $parent in your data-bind, so that should call the method on the parent. Did you mean to have $data.methodThatNeedsAccesToTheParentViewModel as the data-bind? If you did, then you need to look into some kind of pubsub framework, either [knockout postbox](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox/&ei=Qm83UdevN8K3O8X4gJAO&usg=AFQjCNG-FzUVJ5Y20TdRgrG8dZv1CVv4og&sig2=pglMqraisRZqwF703wneSg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU) or the [jquery pubsub plugin](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins&ei=UG83UZ7tD4bKPeTmgJgK&usg=AFQjCNGV8Y2tCgfxdLw-x_AUrMOQc26C1Q&sig2=Qlswes5egQVNURJ0RAQP2A&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU)

Comment: because the method is a prototype then the "this" value is not the instantiated view model (normaly = $parent in  non prototype methods) rather the child in the for each, which I don't want.